# No me funciona el request

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets

estoy haciendo un servlet con jsp y facades y httpsession, mi problema es que no funciona el request, almenos no me los devuelve, trate de printearlos y nada. Trato de ingresar una contrase o un usuario y el problema es que no me recibe creo, almenos lo probe  en el body y no me imprime nada, ahi mismo puse un out.print de rut y pas, pero no me recibe, vi el jsp y me los manda a login?rt=algo&pw=algo , pero los request no me reciben nada. Ademas Repsonse.sendRedirect no  me envia a nada, se queda en el Servlet en vez de enviarme a saldo, espero que me ayuden , si desean mas detalles yo se los puedo enviar.

```
  package servlets;

import entidades.Cliente;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import modelos.ClienteFacade;

/**
 *
 * @author alumnos09
 */
@WebServlet(name = "Login", urlPatterns = {"/Login"})
public class Login extends HttpServlet {

    @EJB
    private ClienteFacade clienteFacade;

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            HttpSession misession= request.getSession(true); 
            String rut = request.getParameter("rt");
            String pas = request.getParameter("pw");
            Cliente cl = clienteFacade.find(rut);
            if (cl.getClave().equalsIgnoreCase(pas)){
            misession.setAttribute(clienteFacade.find(rut).getNombre(), cl);
            PrintWriter pw= response.getWriter();
            pw.println("<html><body>Producto en session</body></html>");
            pw.close();
            response.sendRedirect("/Saldo.jsp");
            }
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet Login</title>");            
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println(clienteFacade.find(rut).getNombre());
            out.println( rut + pas );
            out.println("<h1>Servlet Login at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        }
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

y este es el jsp donde se ingresa y se envia la contraseña con el usuario , desde aca todo bien,me envia al servlet pero no sale del servlet, espero que me ayuden que no entiende por que no llega

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="Login" method="post">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>
                    <input type="text" name="rt" placeholder="IngreseRut">Rut<br>
                    <Input type="password" name="pw" placeholder="Clave">Clave<br>
                </legend>

            </fieldset>
            <input type="submit" value="Ingresar">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Te falta añadir la ruta donde quieres que el form mande la información

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="Login" method="post" action="/ruta_de_tu_servidor">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>
                    <input type="text" name="rt" placeholder="IngreseRut">Rut<br>
                    <Input type="password" name="pw" placeholder="Clave">Clave<br>
                </legend>
        </fieldset>
        <input type="submit" value="Ingresar">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```